# Two-dimensional arrangement practice

Tags: c

First, sorry for my poor language. I'm using VC++ Express myself.

Now I'm studying about arrangements. The book gave me a project like so:

- Make a 5x5 matrix.
- Each column is for subjects (4 of them)
- Each row is for students (same, 4 of them)
- Each cell saves a score.
- At the end of each row/column, sum the row/column.

[image]
<sub>(source: [dcinside.com](http://img2.dcinside.com/viewGimage.php?no=2abcdc2aead569e96abec2b447826b2e8a31ed2bd95886ec8f7114dea41c5e0b50a950ba41f8c050e72c590e2df7750ec3b6ad8afa0bf7f7de8c653d99d03a))</sub>

And this is my answer program:

```
int main(void)
{
int arr[5][5];
int i,j;

while(1)
{
    printf("student: 1.Jim,2.Jombi,3.Joly,4.Moran if you done, type 0\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    if(i=0)
        break;

    printf("subject: 1.english,2.spanish,3.poolish,4.flash\n");
    scanf("%d", &j);

    printf("insult score!\n");
    scanf("%d", arr[i-1][j-1]);//insulting score
}

for(i=0;i<4;i++)//initialization of sum parts
{
    arr[i][4]=0;
    arr[4][i]=0;
}

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        arr[4][i]+=arr[j][i];

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        arr[i][4]+=arr[i][j];


for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);//printing result
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

I completely don't know why this code doesn't work. Even when I tried only "while" part, it didn't work also. Why is this?

Comment: You need to `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: Hint: try to improve the use of whitespace in your programs :) Compare `for(i=0;i<4;i++)` with `for (i=0; i<4; i++)` or even `for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)`. I tend to use the middle one because my fingers type too fast for my brain to force them to use the last one.

Comment: ty pmg, tiny but important hint! nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed, you have an `if` wrong

```
if (i == 0)
/*   ^^^ */
```

And you have a `scanf` wrong too

```
scanf("%d", &arr[i-1][j-1]);
/*         ^^^ */
```

And you really, Really, **REALLY** shoud initialize the array with something (possibly zeroes)

```
int arr[5][5] = {0};
```

Comment: int arr[5][5] = {0}; can this code initialize whole matrix to 0?

Comment: oh, the second stuff you pointed were my major mistake.
it works now! thx!

Comment: This, together with stdio.h and main() (both assumed) has all that I found.  I, too, didn't know about {0} for initialization.  I would have gone for memset or simply looping through.

Comment: donno ewan ill try and post again!

Comment: Yes, `arr[5][5] = {0};` will initialize all 25 elements to zero (your compiler might complain because `arr` elements are arrays themselves and the "proper" _compact_ initialization should be `= {{0}};`, **but the initializer I used works by definition**).

Comment: yeah it works! and i found that if make arr[5][5]={1,2}; it initialize whole matrix to 0 except [0][0],[0][1].

Answer (score 1):

```
if(i=0)
```

I don't know if this is the source of your problem, but this should be:

```
if(i==0)
```

Comment: hm. i tried right after saw your answar/ but still, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The index in your last `for` loop is one-off. Should be `4`, you use `5`.

Comment: that's just for printing entire arrangement. hm.. i think so arr[0][0]to arr[4][4]

Comment: But you've got `i<4` as the exit condition, so the loop never gets run for `i==4`. You could use `i<5` or `i<=4`

Comment: i think there are two kind of 'for'parts
one- to insult data -case i need just arr[0][0]to arr[3][3]
and two- print whole data- case i need arr[0][0]to arr[4][4]

Comment: -1 It is correct to use i<5 to loop through 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 for the result.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

- You're missing the `&` (address-of) operator in your `scanf()` call, so you'll pass the integer in the array instead.
- Consider just doing a simple `memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr);` before the input loop to make sure the array is clear, rather than the nested `for`s to zero out just the sums. Safer, shorter, easier to understand.
- Add instrumentation, such as printing the matrix after the input step, to make sure it looks alright.

Comment: quote "memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr);" means memset(matrixname, initialization, sizeof arr matrix)?
I should try this part. thx!